# PHP file upload,target directory above upload.php file directory

Tags: php, http, file-upload

I'm using a form  to upload a file using php.  It works fine but I want to change the destination upload directory to something farther back up the tree than the upload.php file.  Can't seem to find out how to designate that in the following:

```
$_FILES["file"]["name"] = "Assets/News_Nonhorse/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
    $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

The upload.php file sits in this directory: Admin/

Admin and Assets are on a common parent.
www.website/Assets/News_Nonhorse/
www.website/Admin/upload.php

How do I specify the upload directory?

I thought I remembered something like /../ to specify the site home directory, but can't find it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Think you should use the ../Assets/News_Nonhorse/ syntax

Comment: If an answer to your question on StackOverflow helped to solve your problem, don't forget to accept it and upvote it if you liked it really, really much. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `..` (parent directory). So in your case, you have to specify:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../Assets/News_Nonhorse/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the absolute path of your destination folder. e.g. '/usr/share/nginx/html/upload'

```js
$_FILES["file"]["name"] = "/var/www/html/Assets/News_Nonhorse/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
    $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

In that way, you can use any folder within your webserver where you've rights to edit/write that folder.